# Is there a distribution which looks like this?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I was playing around with some data. And I got a distribution which looks like the following. Does this resemble any of the known distributions?

[image]

Comment: Lognormal distributions are similar, except they vanish at 0.  This might just be a truncated Gaussian.

Comment: It is a good idea to log-log plot your histogram so as to get an idea of the decay rate of the tail. If what you get is linear then your tail has a power law; if what you get is concave, then your tail decays faster than polynomially, e.g. exponentially or like a Gaussian. This is hard to see from a bare histogram. (It's also often hard to see from data, because the tail simply doesn't contain that many data points. Still, it's something to try.)

Comment: @Paul With the lack of symmetry, it is doubtful that it is a truncated Gaussian, but hopefuly, a Rayleigh distribution...

Comment: @JeanMarie rayleigh vanishes at 0, right?

Comment: @Ian thanks, I will try that.

Comment: Yes, a Rayleigh pdf vanishes at 0, but it it is not contradictory with the fact that the initial bin [0, 0.02] collects non-zero values... thus has a non void content.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a Gamma distribution.  These distributions contain a factor of the form $x^n e^{-\lambda x}$.   Run some through a grapher and see what you think.

Comment: The shape of the tail seems somewhat different, no?

Comment: @ncmathsadist but won't it vanish at 0?